# How to read a long value recorded in a Firestore field through a Cloud Function

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have the following function:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.base64ToImage =
  functions.firestore
    .document('documentos/{documentoId}/ocorrencias/{ocorrenciasId}')
    .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
      const ocorrencia = snapshot.data();
      const imagemBase64 = ocorrencia.imagemBase64;
      console.log('String base64: ', imagemBase64); //here it displays only the first 5000 characters but saves the complete string to Firestore.
    });
```

This function is activated when creating a new document in the firestore, the value recorded in the field document.b64 has 200kb, with about 150000 characters, but when trying to read this value it has returned only the first 5000 characters. How to obtain the full amount that is recorded in the Firestore.

Comment: Firestore never truncates any values from a query.  Please edit the question to show the *full* code that doesn't work the way you expect, including steps that anyone can use to reproduce the issue.  Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @DougStevenson I edited my question with the complete code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably just running into a limit on the length of a single log line.  I'm sure if you try to work with the length of the string, it will be fine.  Try logging the length of the string instead to check it:

```
console.log(`Length: ${imagemBase64.length}`)
```

Comment: That's right, I hadn't thought about getting the string length. Thank you very much, now I'm going to the next step which will be to convert to a file. But thanks once and sorry for my bad English.